# How do I get an Express JS substr?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm getting a return error when I try to substr a variable like:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined`

This is my code:

```js
app.get('/reports/FUHAUHS9029019.CSV', function(req, res, next){
    var filepath = req.params.name;
    var ffilepath = filepath.substr(0,12);
    var filename = req.params.name;
    var ffilename = filename.substr(-18);
    
    console.log(ffilepath);

    res.send('filename: ' + req.params.filepath.substr(-18));
    res.download(filename, edifilepath);
});
```

How can i get the substring coming from my file? and trying to apply dynamic router to this router but i'm also not getting anything out of it besides the substr error.

Thank you so much :D

Comment: `req.params` is an empty object because you haven't specified any parameters in your route URL.  Therefore, `req.params.name` is `undefined` and thus you can't call `.substr()` on an `undefined` value.  Please describe what you're actually trying to accomplish in words because you're code does not describe the actual problem to be solved here.

Comment: People could write better and more complete answers if you described in words what exactly you are trying to accomplish with this route.  As it stands now, the question is pretty unclear.  Please show examples of multiple URLs that you wish for the route to match and then describe what you want to accomplish in the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the parameter:

```
app.get('/reports/:name', function(req, res, next){

var filepath = req.params.name;
var ffilepath = filepath.substr(0,12);
var filename = req.params.name;
var ffilename = filename.substr(-18);

console.log(ffilepath);

res.send('filename: ' + ffilename);
//res.download(filename, edifilepath); // also check this line
});
```

Comment: Using hardcoded constants like `12` and `-18` on a dynamic string value specified by the user that can be anything is unlikely to yield a predictably correct result.

Comment: I agree, but maybe he always knows the length of the parameter he's going to send

Comment: I'm just trying to help with the "'substr' of undefined" issue

Comment: No web server can ever know exactly what it is going to be sent.  It is code like this that causes web servers to crash or have vulnerabilities that an attacker can take advantage of.  No assumptions can be made about incoming parameters for a web server on the public internet.  They must all be checked to see if they are what they are supposed to be before using them.  Your introduction of `:name` is perhaps what the OP is interested in though we can't really tell because the question is so unclear.  But, the rest of the code is not correct.

Comment: Yeah, the parameter will always be like that size, the name will change with the time eventually, but always respecting the same name pattern. In my case, when I click the button on my js file, it redirect me to the url that is the same as my route described in /reports/:name. But when it is passing throught the url my app cannot get the final file name in my url and i get this Undefined thing.

Comment: Also, you can't call both `res.send()` and `res.download()` on the same request.  You only get to send ONE response.  Can't send multiple responses to the same request.

Comment: I would suggest you change your answer to one that only teaches about how to specify a parameter in the URL and how to use `req.param` with that parameter and leave the rest of the code out of the answer.

Comment: the problem is in this line: `res.send('filename: ' + req.params.filepath.substr(-18));`, change it for   `res.send('filename: ' + ffilename);  `